# Disable Android Beam in Activity B

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

i have a problem using NFC in 2 activities , the first one A is a Sender activity and the Second one B is a Receiver ..

My Problem is that the Second Activity is prompting to send beam so both application can send and receive ( conflict).

I Have tryed this solution : [Disable beam touch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535823/disable-beam-touch-mode)

i have 2 phones Samsung galaxy S5 4.4.2 and Galaxy S3 4.3 the solution works for the S5 but when i reverse the order the Galaxy S3 Still prompting to send beam ... I don't know whats the problem :/ any help ?

---

ok here is the code

A :

```
public class NFCActivity extends Activity implements NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback {

private EditText mEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_field);

    NfcAdapter mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mEditText.setText("Sorry this device does not have NFC.");
        return;
    }
    if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mEditText.setText("Please activate your NFC !");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable NFC via Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_field);

    NfcAdapter mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mEditText.setText("Sorry this device does not have NFC.");
        return;
    }
    if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mEditText.setText("Please activate your NFC !");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable NFC via Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

      mAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    NfcAdapter  mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    NfcAdapter  mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
    }

}

@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
    String message = mEditText.getText().toString();
    NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", message.getBytes());
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
    return ndefMessage;
}
```

}

B:

```
public class NFCDisplayActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
public NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc_display);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    // Disable This activity from Sending Beams
    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
    //NfcAdapter  mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    ScanNewTicket();
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);



}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    NfcAdapter  mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
    mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, this);

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMessages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        NdefMessage message = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[0]; // only one message transferred

        String Resultcode=new String(message.getRecords()[0].getPayload());


        mTextView.setText(Resultcode);
        if (Resultcode.equals("seif"))
        {
            findViewById(R.id.imageOK).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            findViewById(R.id.imageKO).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    } else
        mTextView.setText("Waiting for Next Ticket Scan");

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getClass());
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pIntent, null, null);

}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    NfcAdapter  mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
    }
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        return; // ignore NFC intents
    }
}
public void ScanNewTicket() {
    Button nextScan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nextscan);
    final Context context = this;
    nextScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   public void onClick(View v)
        {
          /*  Intent intent = new Intent(context, NFCActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();*/

            Intent i = new Intent(context,NFCDisplayActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: show us the code for activities A and B then maybe we can help

Comment: Ok , i have shared it :)